# Laravel testing with password

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've got this test:

```
 /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_register()
    {
        $user = make(User::class, [
            'password'              => 'passwordtest',
            'password_confirmation' => 'passwordtest'
        ])->toArray();

        $response = $this->post('/registreer', $user);

        $response
            ->assertRedirect('/')
            ->assertSessionHas('status', 'Zodra uw account is goedgekeurd ontvangt u een email');

        //Remove password and password_confirmation from array
        array_splice($user,4, 2);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', $user);
    }
```

The problem is that in my user model `password` is **hidden**. So when I `dd($request->all());` in the controller method. The password is not there in my test (only `password_confirmation`).

But when I do this with my registration form manually (without a test) the password field is there when I `dd($request->all());`??!?

Right now I receive red back in my test. It's telling me password is not there.

Why is that how could I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setHidden and setVisble methods to expose properties on a model. And you really shouldn't be testing the password itself, just the fact the record gets saved and the user instance can login.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I've to send a password with the request (in my test) because it's obviously required.

Comment: You could always just call Model::unguard() and fill the password and confirmation then reguard() before the test happens

Comment: Are you using the Laravel test helpers? There are methods that allow you to spoof login and bypass authentication for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'password_confirmation'
    ];
}
```

Password Confirmation will now be hidden when you are converting the user model into an array/json.

The password and password_confirmation are visible to your $request because it is a request object. You are able to see what the browser data sent to your controller.

Comment: So how should I send the password in my test?